# complex functions that already support autograd - Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, reshape, complex-numbers

I am using this customized function to reshape my tensors in the customized loss function.

```
def reshape_fortran(x, shape):
if len(x.shape) > 0:
    x = x.permute(*reversed(range(len(x.shape))))
return x.reshape(*reversed(shape)).permute(*reversed(range(len(shape))))
```

Though, I receive this error:

`RuntimeError: _unsafe_view does not support automatic differentiation for outputs with complex dtype.`

for `reshape_fortran` output.

Do you know what might be the problem? which function is not supported in Pytorch autograd for complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Complex Autograd was in Beta as of version 1.8, but is now stable and should fully support such operations as of [1.9](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.9-released/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by using this function instead, but I have no idea why it was not working and why it is working now:

```
def convert_output84_torch(input):
  shape84 = (8,4)
  T1 = torch.transpose(input,0,2).permute(0,1,2).contiguous()
  T2 = T1.view(shape84[::-1])
  output = torch.transpose(T2,0,1)
  return output
```

I replaced `reshape` with `view`, and it works fine (for now). But as my code was working fine before, I am not sure if it is a long-term solution as I am not aware of the main source.